# IllegalArgumentException Accessing Contacts in Xamarin Forms App

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm attempting to access the users Contacts in a Xamarin Forms app. I've written platform specific implementations and used the DependencyService to call into them which seems to be working OK. However, when I test the Android implementation, I'm getting an error, the code is throwing an IllegalArgumentException at the following code:

```
var uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri;
string[] projection = { ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GivenName,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FamilyName,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.Address};
var phoneLoader = new CursorLoader(Android.App.Application.Context, uri, projection, null, null, null);
var cursor = (Android.Database.ICursor)phoneLoader.LoadInBackground();
```

I've also tried getting a cursor via:

```
var cursor = Forms.Context.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

I've also tried the following:

```
var phoneLoader = new CursorLoader(Android.App.Application.Context);
            phoneLoader.SetProjection(projection);
            phoneLoader.Uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri;
            var cursor = (Android.Database.ICursor)phoneLoader.LoadInBackground();
```

but that throws the exact same error:

```
09-09 14:27:22.163 I/MonoDroid(10022): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
09-09 14:27:22.222 I/MonoDroid(10022): Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data2
09-09 14:27:22.223 I/MonoDroid(10022):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
09-09 14:27:22.223 I/MonoDroid(10022):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method) [0x00068] in <6cd960837cc24c26bab2a0a29b597627>:0 
09-09 14:27:22.223 I/MonoDroid(10022):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr jmethod) [0x0000e] in <06064416b46d4ffbb3484c957929a39f>:0 
09-09 14:27:22.223 I/MonoDroid(10022):   at Android.Content.CursorLoader.LoadInBackground () [0x00043] in <06064416b46d4ffbb3484c957929a39f>:0
```

And its on this line:

```
cursor = (Android.Database.ICursor)phoneLoader.LoadInBackground();
```

Can anyone see what is wrong in the above code that is causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data2

The column does exist in your database, if you haven't added the column to a thing called the projection map, you'll get the "invalid column" error you're seeing.

In projection, `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds` is not a part of `Contacts` table which you are querying.

> access the users Contacts in a Xamarin Forms app

Here is another solution to access the user contacts :

```
//Get all the names of the contacts and their phone number
ContentResolver cr = ContentResolver;
ICursor cur = cr.Query(ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri,null, null, null, null);
if (cur.Count > 0)
{
    while (cur.MoveToNext())
    {
        String id = cur.GetString(cur.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id));
        String name = cur.GetString(cur.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName));

         if (cur.GetInt(cur.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.HasPhoneNumber)) > 0)
         {
             ICursor pCur = cr.Query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri,
             null,
             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.ContactId + " = ?",
             new String[] { id }, 
             null);
             while (pCur.MoveToNext())
             {
                 String phoneNo = pCur.GetString(pCur.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number));
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo);
             }
             pCur.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing uri to use ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri

```
var uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri;
string[] projection = {
               ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id,
               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GivenName,
               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FamilyName,
               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number,
               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.Address
          };
var loader = new CursorLoader(Android.App.Application.Context, uri, projection, null, null, null);
var cursor = loader.LoadInBackground();
```